# Different types of screen in the sw320dp-hdpi layout category look very different

Tags: android, layout, user-interface, screen

I've layout-sw320dp-hdpi folder with following xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/wall1Layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/wall4" tools:context=".FireRoomActivity">

    <Button android:id="@+id/fishtank" android:layout_width="170dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp" android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_marginRight="70dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="75dp" android:onClick="fillBottle"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent" />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

I've looked at 3 types of screen that fall into sw320dp-hdpi category: 1) samsung galaxy s2(480x800), 2) 3.7'' WVGA(480X800) (this is Nexus One) and 3) 3.7'' FWVGA(480X854).

Two questions:

1) The problem arises between galaxy s2 and Nexus One, as you can see in the screenshots bellow, the button "fishtank" is slightly off in the nexus one. I guess that's because the first one has menu, home and back as part of the screen, i.e. as part of the 480x800 while the second one doesn't. Please correct me if I'm wrong, I just don't see any reason why would the button be in different locations if both screens are the same size

2) The problem arises between 3.7'' WVGA(480X800) and 3.7'' FWVGA(480X854). As you can see from the screenshots bellow the difference in the location of "fishtank" button is considerable. What could I do to fix it? May be there are layout tricks that I don't know about

**Samsung galaxy s2(480x800)**

[image: Samsung galaxy s2(480x800)]

**Nexus One(3.7'' WVGA(480X800))**

[image: Nexus One(3.7'' WVGA(480X800))]

**3.7'' FWVGA(480X854)**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, I think it's really difficult to set the suitable size of button using XML. 'Cause, you know, a lot of screen size and dpi. The pixel size of your Background image will be changed every time...

So, you can solve this problem using codes.
Try below...

No size, No alignment...

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/wall1Layout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/wall4" tools:context=".FireRoomActivity">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/fishtank"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:onClick="fillBottle" />
```

```
/* Background Size */
final double BG_REAL_WIDTH_PX = 510;
final double BG_REAL_HEIGHT_PX = 332;

/* Fish Tank Size */
final double FISH_TANK_REAL_WIDTH_PX = 177;
final double FISH_TANK_REAL_HEIGHT_PX = 90;

/* Start point */
final double FISH_TANK_START_X = 260;
final double FISH_TANK_START_Y = 77;

private void setButtonPosition() {
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    WindowManager winMan = (WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    winMan.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);

    double dScaleWidth = (double) displayMetrics.widthPixels / BG_REAL_WIDTH_PX;
    double dScaleHeight = (double) displayMetrics.heightPixels / BG_REAL_HEIGHT_PX;

    double dPosX = dScaleWidth * FISH_TANK_START_X;
    double dPosY = dScaleHeight * FISH_TANK_START_Y;

    double dTobeFishTankWidth = dScaleWidth * FISH_TANK_REAL_WIDTH_PX;
    double dTobeFishTankHeight = dScaleHeight * FISH_TANK_REAL_HEIGHT_PX;

    Button btnFishTank = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fishtank);

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = btnFishTank.getLayoutParams();
    params.width = (int) dTobeFishTankWidth;
    params.height = (int) dTobeFishTankHeight;
    btnFishTank.setLayoutParams(params);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
        btnFishTank.setX((int) dPosX);
        btnFishTank.setY((int) dPosY);
    }
    else {
        //TODO: Code for low level OS under 11
    }
}
```

Result is... (on 1280x720)

[image]

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer, upvote for that. But I have buttons all over the game (around 50). So I wish there was xmll-wise answer for the problem. Btw, will this code work for any possible screen? For tablets, for small and for other large screens?

Comment: Ok, I checked, it does work for all screen sizes. If I absolutely have to do it this way, how can I calculate starting point, width and height of background and the button itself?

Comment: How did you calculate BG_REAL_WIDTH_PX, BG_REAL_HEIGHT_PX , FISH_TANK_REAL_WIDTH_PX, FISH_TANK_REAL_HEIGHT_PX, FISH_TANK_START_X, FISH_TANK_START_Y? Is there universal way of finding out those numbers for any button?

Comment: Thank you for up voting. And I think there are no way to calculate those points automatically. I picked each points by hand. If you want to do this without irritate things, split the image for a background and button's background. I have no experience of the game development. So, That is all that I can advise... What about a study for 2d/3d graphics? :) Good Luck!

Comment: Thank you. What is bc_real_width (height)? is it the screen size in pixels?

Comment: @Nazerke BG_REAL_WIDTH/HEIGHT is the real size in pixel of background. :)

Comment: Aren't you saying that you used 780x1280?

Comment: @Nazerke 720x1280 is the device's resolution(Samsung Galaxy S2). 510x332 is the size of your background image.